# Java generics with multi interface casting

Tags: java, generics

Consider I have:

```
public interface I1{}
public interface I2{}
public class A implements I1, I2{}
public class B implements I1, I2{}
```

Why I can't have a method:

```
public static <K extends I1 & I2> K get(){
      if(some condition)
          return new A();  // I am getting "type mismatch" error
      else
          return new B(); // I am getting "type mismatch" error
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
     I1 myThing = get(); // because I want to use only methods from I1 interface..
}
```

It only works if I add a cast like this "return (K) new A();" and even then it gives an unsafe cast warning.

I could just create an interface that extends both I1,I2, but if I start doing that I will end up with a lot of classes and messy code.
What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Because if the caller calls YourClass.<Foo>get(), the method should return a Foo, not an A or a B.

Comment: @JBNizet answers the "why doesn't this work?" part. As for the "what is the correct way" (to get an intersection type in Java), I think you do need to make that extra interface.

Comment: @JBNizet what do you mean YourClass.<Foo>get(), its not even a legal syntax

Comment: Yes, it is (provided the class where the method get() is defined is named YourClass, but we don't know how it's named). By defining the method this way, you let the caller decide what type the method should return (Foo in my example), provided this type extends I1 & I2. So if the caller has a class named Foo, which implements I1 and I2, and calls your method, this way (or just uses Foo foo = YourClass.get()), then it will cause a ClassCastException.

Comment: @JBNizet Obviously if you call Foo foo = YourClass.get() it should be a cast exception even if foo implements I1 and I2, but I am using I1 myThing = get();

Comment: Then make your method return I1, not K. It doesn't need to be generic if the method is supposed to return an I1. Declaring it the way you declare it makes the code Foo foo = YourClass.get() valid, and expected. If it shouldn't be, then it shows that the way you declare the method is incorrect.

Comment: I once asked a similar question, which greatly increased my understanding of generic return types in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654841/java-compile-error-in-method-with-generic-return-type

Comment: @JBNizet but I was to use I1 for some cases and I2 for other cases

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create that "intersection type interface", I suppose you could do

```
public static I1 getAsI1(){
      if(some condition)
          return new A();  // I am getting "type mismatch" error
      else
          return new B(); // I am getting "type mismatch" error
}

public static I2 getAsI2(){
   return (I2) getAsI1();  // above implementation guarantees the cast will work
}
```

Then the caller can choose which interface they want.