# how to override methods with generic return type in java in case of multi level inheritance

Tags: java

I have an abstract class containing an abstract method which returns a generic type.
lets say

```
abstract class AbstractSample{
  //class members

  //this method needs to be overriden
  public abstract SampleBuilder<? extends AbstractSample,?> copyBuilder ();

  //other methods
  //builder
  public static abstract class SampleBuilder<T extends AbstractSample, B extends SampleBuilder<T,B>> {
    //properties
    private String as;

    public SampleBuilder(AbstractSample object) {
      this.as = object.as;
    }

    public B as(String as) {
      this.as = as;
      return (B)this;
    }

    public abstract T build(); 
  }
}
```

Now I have a class Sample1 which extends this class and implements the method copyBuilder()

```
public class Sample1 extends AbstractSample {
  //class members

  @Override
  public AbstractSample.SampleBuilder<Sample1,Sample1.Builder> copyBuilder()      {
    return new Sample1.Builder(this);
  }

  //other methods
  //builder
  public static class Builder extends SampleBuilder<Sample1,Builder> {
    //implementation
    //containing members and methods
  }
}
```

There is another class Sample2 which is a subclass of Sample1.
When I try to override the method copyBuilder() in this class, I am getting issues in the return type.

```
class Sample2 extends Sample1 {
  //class members

  // I am not allowed to implement this as below
  @Override
  public AbstractSample.SampleBuilder<Sample2,Sample2.Builder> copyBuilder() { 
    return new Sample2.Builder(this) ; 
  }

  //other methods
  //builder
  public static class Builder extends SampleBuilder<Sample2,Builder> {
    //implementation
    //containing members and methods
  }
}
```

IntelliJ says the method clashes with the one in the superclass , attempting to use incompatible return type.

Could anyone suggest how to implement the method copyBuilder() in Sample2 so that it returns Sample2.Builder .

Comment: You may be interested in this question concerning generic return types in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654841/java-compile-error-in-method-with-generic-return-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't like a part `B extends SampleBuilder<T, B>`. Why is it even useful to reference itself?

Anyway You can make it work if You change

`SampleBuilder<Sample1,Sample1.Builder> copyBuilder()`

to

`SampleBuilder<? extends Sample1, ?> copyBuilder()`

A complete example is below

```
public class Test {
abstract static class AbstractSample {

    private String as;

    //this method needs to be overriden
    public abstract SampleBuilder<? extends AbstractSample, ?> copyBuilder();

    public static abstract class SampleBuilder<T extends AbstractSample, B extends SampleBuilder<T, B>> {

        private String as;

        public SampleBuilder(AbstractSample object) {
            this.as = object.as;
        }

        public B as(String as) {
            this.as = as;
            return (B) this;
        }

        public abstract T build();
    }
}

static class Sample1 extends AbstractSample {

    @Override
    public SampleBuilder<? extends Sample1, ?> copyBuilder() {
        return new Builder(this);
    }

    public static class Builder extends SampleBuilder<Sample1, Builder> {

        public Builder(Sample1 sample1) {
            super(sample1);
        }

        @Override
        public Sample1 build() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

static class Sample2 extends Sample1 {

    @Override
    public SampleBuilder<? extends Sample2, ?> copyBuilder() {
        return new Builder(this);
    }

    public static class Builder extends SampleBuilder<Sample2, Builder> {

        public Builder(Sample2 sample2) {
            super(sample2);
        }

        @Override
        public Sample2 build() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: this means a class is a subclass of itself  , when I call copyBuilder() from an object of Sample1 , then it returns Sample1.Builder which is getting typecasted to SampleBuilder<? extends Sample1, ?> ....does this mean Sample1 extends Sample1?

Comment: @bushra Changing `Sample1.Builder` to `?` makes `copyBuilder()` method override'able. You cannot override a method and make the return type different or more general.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need generics here. This works perfectly:

```
abstract class AbstractSample {

    public abstract SampleBuilder copyBuilder ();

    public static abstract class SampleBuilder {
        public abstract AbstractSample build();
    }
}

public class Sample1 extends AbstractSample {

    @Override
    public Sample1.Builder copyBuilder() {
        return new Sample1.Builder(this);
    }

    public static class Builder extends SampleBuilder {
        public Builder() { }
        public Builder(Sample1 d) { }

        @Override
        public Sample1 build() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class Sample2 extends Sample1 {
    @Override
    public Sample2.Builder copyBuilder() {
        return new Sample2.Builder(this) ;
    }

    public static class Builder extends Sample1.Builder {
        public Builder(Sample2 d) { }

        @Override
        public Sample2 build() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: But I do need generics here.  let me give the detailed implementation of the builder.