# Return ? extends Type

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to have a method signature that looks as such:

```
public <? extends IDto> convertToResponseDto();
```

I came up with this from a valid signature that looks like:

```
public List<? extends IDto> convertToResponseDto();
```

As it turns out `Type <? extends IDto>` is not a valid return type. I feel like the intention of what I am trying to return is quite clear, but not sure what the correct syntax is

**EDIT**

This question was answered by @ErwinBolwidt, but gives a new problem in a use case. I have a case where I am using generics:

```
protected final <E extends IDto> E findOneInternal(final Long id) {
        return getService().findOne(id).convertToResponseDto();
}
```

In this case, convertToResponseDto() returns IDto, and not the concrete class, as its not known at this pint because it gets the service of type T

Comment: Just use `public IDto convertToResponseDto();`.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn i have a requirement that the result of that method returns as the concrete class (whatever ? is). Is the best way to handle this just to use a cast?

Comment: If you overload it, you can use a subtype. Otherwise stuff gets really complicated when you do things like `<T> T iCanReturnAnything()`.

Comment: You can override an interface method or superclass method with a more specific subtype as the return type. Say your superclass says `public IDto convertToDTO()`, then your subclass can say `public MySpecificDTO convertToDTO()` - that's implied and doesn't need any generics.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt so in my class that implements that interface I should be able to write: `public UserDto convertToResponseDto(){}`? I get an error with this

Comment: What error did you get ?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt i take it back, it works, problem resolved

Comment: [What is a covariant return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882584/what-is-a-covariant-return-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override an interface method or superclass method with a more specific subtype as the return type. Say your superclass says

```
public IDto convertToDTO()
```

Then your subclass can say

```
public MySpecificDTO convertToDTO()
```

That's implied by the Java language and doesn't need any generics.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a generic type

```
public <T extends IDto> T convertToResponseDto();
```

Comment: I once learned why returning a generic like this is not a great idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36654841/java-compile-error-in-method-with-generic-return-type